# PHP - Send ImageMagick object to Telegram through cURL

Tags: php, curl, imagemagick, telegram-bot

I usually send image files to the Telegram servers (https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendphoto) through cURL as follows:

```
$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type:multipart/form-data"));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, URL); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array("photo"     => "@" . FILE_PATH, )); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILESIZE, filesize(FILE_PATH));
$output = curl_exec($ch);
```

This works great, the server receives and understands my images.

Instead of sending an image stored on disc, I'd like to send the image stored within an `Imagick()` object.

How can I achieve this directly in PHP (without outputting the `Imagick` object to disc and sending as above)?

Comment: You have to convert the object to something that is transportable, such as a file or a json string or a bin2hex string... Then, you need to convert it back to an object on the other end. That is if you want to do it with curl. The other option is to set up sockets on both ends and share objects (shared memory) between the hosts. Converting the object to text and then back to an object will be a hell of a lot easier.

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't an option; I'm using this to communicate with a server I cannot control. I'll update the question accordingly.